# How to pre select a state in Rails Carmen state_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carmen

What are the options I can pass in a state_select. I am trying to do :selected => state and its not working.

```
<%= f.state_select :state, 'US', {:prompt => '--Select One--', :selected => state}, :tabindex => autotab, :id => 'state_select, :state => state'%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use state_select to do it. You'll have to use **select** with the **state_options_for_select** function in order to enter your selected state:

```
<%= f.select :state, state_options_for_select(state_to_select, country_code) %>
```

That should get you there.